# How to trigger a particular Transaction at same time

Tags: jmeter

I have the following situation:

I have total of 4 Transactions; 
**i.** Login
**ii.** Landing Page
**iii.** User Page
**iv.** View Users Page

After performing all the above 3 Transactions, I want trigger the last Transaction i.e. "**View Users Page**" at a time for 20 Threads. How do I achieve, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) and set number to 20 if what you want is to have at least 20 threads calling the request at the same time.

If not, please clarify how much threads you have and how you configured thread group.

Comment: Yes, Synchronizing Timer fits well on my requirement. Thanks.